What is the term for the shading across anime characters' faces when they are mortified or terrified?
I often see in anime that when a character is mortified, terrified, etc., this shading comes across their face. Different from the forehead shading. I just want to know if it has a name.


I think that is either "Straight Line" shading or "Solid Shading".

One of the places I know where the shading is used is depicting serious scenario in a goofy anime (to portray contrast). A recent example I know is when supposed GF of Yuji Itadori asks Nobara if she likes him or not (S2 of JJK). See: https://youtu.be/8BS9Li0ls6Q?si=aMg4e_AMgPDbdFoU
